# Get the indice of array if some condition is met in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can i get an array of all the indices of array if its elements's conditions are met. For example:

```
a = [32, 35, 68, 44, 8, 45]
```

Tthe method should return an array `[2, 3, 5]` with condition > 35.

Comment: `result = []; a.each.with_index {|e, i| result << i if e > 35}`

Comment: @iamnotmaynard - it would be more Rubyish to construct the array with `inject` instead of building it up incrementally in a loop.  Something like this: `result = a.each_with_index.inject([]) {|r,(e,i)| e > 35 ? r + [i] : r }`

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a duplicate, but a quick search didn't find anything.

The easiest way is probably to use `each_with_index`:

```
irb(main):001:0> a=[32,35,68,44,8,45] #=> [32, 35, 68, 44, 8, 45]
irb(main):002:0> a.each_with_index.select { |n,i| n > 35 }.map &:last     
=> [2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Mark, if only you were 10 sec late :)

Comment: Alternative: `a.map.with_index{ |n,i| n>35 ? i : nil }.compact`